# error while converting excel file to json in node js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to convert an excel file to node js. At first I am uploading the file to the server. Then after uploading I am trying to convert the uploaded excel file to Json.

Here is the brinks.js from where i am calling common.js. First i am writing the file and then trying to read it from the returned path.

```
const commonController = require('./common');
const brinksFilePath = './uploads/';
const model = require('../../../models/report/report');




async function insert_brinks(request) {
    
    
try {
   
    var uploadFilePath = await commonController.uploadFile(request.payload.brinks, request.payload.id);
    if (uploadFilePath.length > 0) {
        
    //     console.log("upload file path length --", uploadFilePath.length)
           var jsonData = await commonController.convertExcelToJson(uploadFilePath, 'Sheet1', request.payload.id, request.payload.brinks.hapi.filename) 
    //     console.log("uploadFilePath--", uploadFilePath);
    }   
    
   
} catch (error) {
   console.log("error ", error)
}
  
    return true;
}

module.exports = {
    insert_brinks
}
```

commom.js

```
const node_xj = require("xls-to-json");
const pathLib = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

let convertExcelToJson = async (filePath, sheetName, id, fileName) => { 

    try {

        node_xj(
            {
                input: pathLib.join(process.cwd(), 'uploads', id, fileName),             
                sheet: sheetName, 
                rowsToSkip: 3, 
                allowEmptyKey: false,default: true
            },
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("converted data -----", result);
                }
            }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error while converting the file -------", error)
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Getting error as

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Desktop\App\amt\api\uploads\file.xlsx
```

But if I check the path, File is available in the same path .

Comment: Probably you are trying to convert the file before it gets uploaded at path: ```C:\Users\Desktop\App\amt\api\uploads\file.xlsx```

Comment: i have added await while calling

Comment: Can you share the complete flow?

Comment: @RaghuChahar. I have updated the complete flow here .

Comment: Could you check the value of `id` inside `convertExcelToJson`? It seems to be missing, as it does not appear in the path shown in the error message.

Comment: I am able to print that.